# How does Laravel parse the .env file?

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, laravel-5

I would like to mimic the way a Laravel application has it's environment variables set via a `.env` file.

```
APP_ENV=local
DB_DATABASE=fruits
DB_USERNAME=fruituser
DB_PASSWORD=secretpassword
```

So it can then set default fallbacks in `config.php` like this:

```
return [
    'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),
];
```

However I am having trouble digging through the framework code to find the bit where it parses the text in `.env` and turns it into proper PHP variables.

I have found the definition of the `env()` helper function in `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php`:

```
function env($key, $default = null)
{
    $value = getenv($key);

    if ($value === false) {
        return value($default);

    }
...
```

...but that calls another global helper function called `getenv()` and that is where the trail goes cold.

I suspect we might be down to Symfony level now but alas I cannot find the definition of `getenv()` and your help and guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: getenv is a PHP function, it'll be documented on PHP's site

Comment: https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv

Comment: That being said, Laravel uses vlucas/dotenv to parse .env files

Comment: Ah! [FACEPALM] I can't believe I didn't think that it might be a native PHP thing. Thank you!

Comment: @ThomasMoors Thank you, by the way, how would I have found this myself without help? What stone did I leave unturned?

Comment: You could check Laravel's `composer.json` to find this library included. And googling for `env library php` would also give you the same result. However I don't blame you for not knowing this!

Comment: I just searched `'.env'` in project files. [Search results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTmug.png)

Comment: Take a look at `\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadEnvironmentVariables`, it's in the `$bootstrappers` array in the kernel.

Comment: @morph Thanks for the pointer. By the way, I found it was called `\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration.php` in my Laravel 5.3 and 5.4 version projects. It's called `LoadEnvironmentVariables` in version 5.5, you sir are on the bleeding edge! :-)

Answer (score 10):

Laravel Uses this libarary for it

https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv